# Filtering in hive

Tags: hadoop, filter, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a hive table demo (id bigint, items string) where dataset is a comma separated set of strings like

```
id  dataset 
1   ,2,asd,as,a,1 
2   sda,saa,2,fds
```

Is there a native way I can filter out the non-numeric strings and keep only the numeric strings other than exploding the table, filtering and then grouping by or writing my own UDF.

```
id  dataset 
1   2,1 
2   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  id
       ,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(dataset,'(?<=^|,)((\\d+)|([^,]*))(?=,|$)','$2'),'^,+|,+$|(,)+','$1')

from    demo
;
```

---

```
+----+-----+
| id | c1  |
+----+-----+
|  1 | 2,1 |
|  2 | 2   |
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression like this:

```
select id
  ,regexp_replace(dataset, '(,[a-zA-Z]+|^,|[a-zA-Z]+,)' , '') as dataset
 from yourdata;
```

This results in:

```
id dataset
1 2,1
2 2
```

Comment: No. test yourself with the following strings: `@,#,$`,`10x`,`a,,,b`,`a,b`,`1,,2`

Comment: I used data provided by op

Comment: Here is another "solution" that "does what the op asked for": `select regexp_replace(dataset,'\\D+(\\d)\\D+(,\\d)?$','$1$2') from demo`